# What is the limit value

Tags: calculus, limits

> The value of $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(5^x + 5^{3x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ is...

My approach :

> $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \left(5^x + 5^{3x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
>   $$=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left(5^x\left(1 + 5^{2x}\right)\right)^\frac{1}{x}$$
>   $$=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} \left(5^x\right)^\frac{1}{x}\left(1 + 5^{2x}\right)^\frac{1}{x}$$
>   $$=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty} 5\left(1 + 5^{2x}\right)^\frac{1}{x}$$

But I don't know how to proceed. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:
$$\left(5^x+5^{3x}\right)^{1/x}=5^3\left(1+5^{-2x}\right)^{1/x}$$
Can you finish now? The limit of the last expression in parentheses is not an indeterminate form now.

Comment: Okay...i think i get it, is the answer 125?

Comment: @Vann yes, it's $125$

Answer (score 2):

$$(5^{3x})^{1/x}<(5^x+5^{3x})^{1/x} < 5^3(1+5^{-2x})^{1/x}$$
So by sandwich theorem the required limit is 125.

Answer (score 1):

From your last step

$$\left(1 + 5^{2x}\right)^{1/x}=\Big[5^{2x}(1+5^{-2x})\Big]^{1/x}=\Big(5^{2}\Big)\Big(1+5^{-2x}\Big)^{1/x}$$

then take the limit as $x\to\infty$ and the above expression will approach $25$ giving you the desired result.